# Database table archiving

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure (SP) in order to archive a table within my production database which is about 1TB.

The production DB runs on Linux SUSE OS and the destination location for the archive is Windows Server 2012.

The SP will recurrently archive 42 days of data from the production table to the  archiving destination table and clean up the production table from the archived data to free up space.

I really don't have the skills to write this stored procedure and also put in place a cron job or a script that will perform this task automatically.

Please anyone to help me out with the above?

Comment: We need more clarification.  Are you trying to archive to files, or to another running PostgreSQL instance?

Comment: I am trying to archive to another instance not to files.

Answer (score 3):

One options is the one a_horse_with_no_name gave you, to insert to the foreign table, and delete.  Although I would prefer to do it in one statement rather than two:

```
with t as (
  delete from local_table
  where created_at_column <= current_date - 42 returning *
) 
insert into archive_table
select *
from t;
```

You might have to list out the columns rather than using *, depending on whether the archive table has exactly the same columns in the same order.

If you are starting out way behind, then you might want to use a number greater than 42, and so limiting the amount of load you put on the system at any one time.  Gradually dropping it on repeated runs towards 42 until you reach it.

Another option would be to use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html) to replicate data (other than deletes) on the fly to the archive table.  But this only works if the only deletes on the master table are the ones done for archival purposes.  If there deletes for other purposes, this won't work.  If you do it this way, then you need no FDW (unless you need it to query back to the archive), and you only need to do deletes on the master, as the archive server has had the inserts already performed in close to real time.

In either case, I don't really see an advantage to putting this logic into a stored procedure.  If you need to use psql to invoke the stored procedure, you might as well use psql to execute the SQL directly, unless you will be executing it from multiple different places. But calling the procedure might be fewer letters, and so make the cron file prettier. (Although many people would say the crontab should only call a shell script which runs the psql command, not run the psql command directly, in which case that wouldn't matter)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html) in the Linux server that points to the Postgres running on the Windows server.

Then you can move the rows with an INSERT and a DELETE statement

```
insert into archive_table (col1, col2, col3)
select c1, c2, c3
from local_table
where created_at_column <= current_date - 42;: -- rows older than 42 days

delete from local_table
where created_at_column <= current_date - 42;
```

Where `archive_table` is the foreign table that "points"  to the Windows server.

The DELETE will probably be quite slow (the more rows you archive, the slower it will be), a faster way would be to partition the table e.g. by month and then detach old partitions from the table.